# Need guidance in forming a query in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
SELECT id,
    login_id,
    count,
    case when count = 0 then 'Cat_A'
       WHEN  count between 1 and 10 then 'Cat_B'
       WHEN  count >  10 then 'Cat_C' 
       WHEN count IS NULL THEN 'Cat D'
       END as Category
FROM 
    (
        select id,login_id,min(ord_count) AS count
        FROM table_1 X
            JOIN table_2 Y
                ON X.id_col = Y.id_col
        WHERE date = '2022-02-02'
            AND login_id = 'True'
        group by id,login_id
    )A
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT id,COUNT(X.ord_no) AS count_of_orders
            FROM table_1 X
            WHERE X.date = '2022-02-02'
            group by id
        )B
        ON A.id=B.id
```

When I join these two tables, I'm getting NULL values for the unmatched records.
I need to replace those NULL records to some hardcoded value say 'XYZ'.

Any guidance on how to achieve this please?

Comment: You can do something like `NVL( COLUMN_TO_CHECK , 'XYZ' )` unless there's more that needs to happen here.

Comment: This query won't run in its current state as column `id` is present in both `a` and `b` aliased derived tables. As far as I can tell you are only using columns from alias `a`, so why even join? At any rate, it's not clear what you mean "NULL values for the unmatched records". It's hard to talk about data and records when all we can are given is broken sql. Please share sample data and desired results.

Comment: Will add it shortly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- So the top level select needs to name which ID it is using (other DB's don't require this snowflake does), given you are selecting from `A` and `b.id` might be missing, it should be `a.id`
- `count_of_orders` is not used, so currently the LEFT JOIN to `B` is pointless, given your question is about LEFT JOIN this must be the column you a referring to??
- The replace NULL values can be done via [COALESCE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/coalesce.html) or [NVL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl.html) or [ZEROIFNULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/zeroifnull.html), given the only null thing is a count, zeroifnull seems to make sense here.

which all make me think your SQL needs to look like:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.login_id,
    a.count,
    case 
        WHEN a.count = 0 then 'Cat_A'
        WHEN a.count between 1 and 10 then 'Cat_B'
        WHEN a.count >  10 then 'Cat_C' 
        WHEN a.count IS NULL THEN 'Cat D'
    END as Category,
    ZEROIFNULL(b.count_of_orders) as count_of_orders
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id,
        login_id,
        min(ord_count) AS count
    FROM table_1 AS X
    JOIN table_2 AS Y
        ON X.id_col = Y.id_col
    WHERE date = '2022-02-02'
        AND login_id = 'True'
    group by id,login_id
) as A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        x.id,
        COUNT(X.ord_no) AS count_of_orders
    FROM table_1 as X
    WHERE X.date = '2022-02-02'
    group by x.id
)as B
    ON A.id=B.id
```

The `A` sub-select really should use the aliases you named `X`, `Y` so we know which tables `id`, `login_id`, `ord_count`, & `date` all come from.